# Python Weasyprint to Google Bucket

Tags: python, weasyprint, google-bucket

I am using Google Functions in order to generate PDFs.

I want to store the PDFs in a Google Bucket.

I know that I can store PDFs as a file using the following code:

```
# Write PDF to HTML
pdf = "<html><title>Hello</title><body><p>Hi!</p></body></html>"

# HTML to PDF at local disk
document = weasyprint.HTML(string=pdf, encoding='UTF-8')
document.write_pdf(f"Hello.pdf")
```

However I want to store it in a Google Bucket, so I have tried the following code :

```
# Write PDF to HTML
pdf = "<html><title>Hello</title><body><p>Hi!</p></body></html>"

# HTML to PDF in Google Bucket
document = weasyprint.HTML(string=pdf, encoding='UTF-8')
client = storage.Client()
bucket = client.get_bucket("monthly-customer-reports")
blob = bucket.blob("Hello.pdf")
with blob.open("w") as f:
    f.write(str(document))
```

This stored a PDF in my Google Bucket but it was invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to write the string representation of the `document` object to the file, but this is not a PDF binary data, what you could do is convert to convert to binary then write it directly to Google Cloud storage.

```
from google.cloud import storage
import weasyprint

pdf = "<html><title>Hello</title><body><p>Hi!</p></body></html>"

document = weasyprint.HTML(string=pdf, encoding='UTF-8')
pdf_bytes = document.write_pdf()

client = storage.Client()
bucket = client.get_bucket("monthly-customer-reports")
blob = bucket.blob("Hello.pdf")
blob.upload_from_string(pdf_bytes, content_type='application/pdf')
```